# VBA and Access, trying to Combine two types of outputs, both from the same field, and display the associated sums under one newly created type

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I'm pretty new to programming in VBA and using Access in general.  I'm trying to design queries for an industry survey, where I need to display sales sums for each of our various distribution channels.

Currently, my query output looks like this:

```
DistChannel               Deposits
Bank                      2002744.05
Career Agent              34108.82
Independent Agents        747001.59
Independent Broker-Dealer 125647.55
Other                     3066.56
```

I'd like to have it display Career Agent and Indepenent Agents under a new row, summing the two deposit totals:

```
DistChannel               Deposits
Bank                      2002744.05
Independent Producers     781110.41
Independent Broker-Dealer 125647.55
Other                     3066.56
```

How would I go about identifying each output and it's correlated deposit sum from a table in VBA?

Comment: I'm looking at some pre-existing code

Comment: What code? Show us. Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I'm looking at some prexisiting code, but i'm not sure what the syntax to reference actual entries would look like, or how to relate the deposits to the newly defined Independent Producers field.  something like newTbl.Fields(Independent Producers) = oldTbl.Fields("Career Agent"); newTbl.Fields(Independent Producers) = oldTbl.Fields("Independent Agents")

Comment: I don't see why you're wanting to use VBa when you can do this with the sql query....